# Does the ASP.NET framework have to be installed to run at vb.net Console Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, console-application

Question, I have a need to run a vb.net console application across a multiple servers. I'm wondering if the ASP.NET framework is required to be installed on each of the assets in order to run?

Comment: pretty much yes.  every server that will run the app locally needs to have the framework.

Comment: @Brian - What does a console app have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: If you use any of the net libraries which I assume he did since he said vb.net then having the framework installed has a lot to do with it.

Comment: @Brian - the .NET framework, but not ASP.NET.

Comment: hence the reason I wrote "the framework".  the op also clearly says "the ASP.NET FRAMEWORK"

Comment: @Brian - "The ASP.NET Framework" is not what he needs installed.  See Matt Wilko's answer below.

Comment: see my comment.  I never said "ASP.Net Framework"  Everyone else who has answered this seems to understand the difference.  Not sure why you are having difficulty or if you are just being nit picky.

Comment: @Brian - Sorry for being nitpicky.  I was genuinely confused by your answer.  The op asked if ASP.NET framework was required, and your first comment started with "pretty much yes."  I took that to mean that either 1) you thought that the ASP.NET web framework needed to be installed, or 2) you considered ASP.NET framework and .NET framework to be synonymous.  The other answers said "no", and went on to explain that they are not synonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your understanding of the terminology/technologies is slightly skewed:-

ASP.NET is a web application framework ([more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)). In order to run a *Web Server* that serves up ASP.NET pages you will need the .NET framework installed on the *Web Server Machine*. Clients that connect to the web server do not need the .NET Framework installed as they just use a web browser.

If you want to run a *console application* on any machine, that machine needs the .NET framework installed on it.

It makes no difference if the console application or web application is written in C# or VB.NET, the same rules still apply.

Comment: I'm awarding you the answer as I felt you provided the best explanation and would be a good response to those looking to answer the same question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, ASP.NET is not required. However, appropriate version of .NET Framework is required to be installed on the machine that is supposed to run the application.

Comment: Thanks everyone for this feedback. The ASP.NET vs .NET Framework was me just trying to get a question submitted in a rush. I understand the difference. Again, I appreciate the feedback.